# Dart: Get the subtype of a generic List type

Tags: dart, flutter

Consider the following method:

```
static void parse<T>(String input, T instance)
```

There could be a case that `T` is a type of `List`. How do I get the subtype of the `List`? Note that there are no elements in the `List` at this moment. So doing e.g. `List[0].runtimeType` is no option.

If `T` is of type `List<Foo>`, I want to get `Foo`.

How can one do this in Dart?

Comment: I doubt it is possible.

Comment: You can't currently do that. If you know all the types it might be, you can exhaustively test `instance is List<Foo>`. `instance if List<Bar>`, etc., but there is no way to take something you know is a `List` and get its element type as a type. If you can use mirrors, you can perhaps get the type as a `Type` object from `reflect(instance).type.typeArguments[0].reflectee`. You can't do a lot of good with a `Type` object, though.

Comment: @lrn thanks! However I am using another version of the reflection. It's called reflectable dart, but it does not work on lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's (kinda) possible to do it, however it is a very ugly workaround. A condition is that you **must** initialize the list before being able to access it's type.

```
List<Something> someList = new List<Something>();
String type = someList.runtimeType.toString(); // List<Something>
```

Then you are able to read the type and do stuff with it.

Comment: AND you cannot do obfuscate for dart codes, the runtime type will be obfuscated too. So the type will be List<Afc> or something like.

Comment: In other words, it won't work in release mode.

Answer (score 1):

This particular feature is not available, as it would complicate tree-shaking.

Depending on your use-case, you might be able to get away with something like:

```
void parseList<T>(String input, List<T> instance) {
  // T is now the static type of List<T>
}
```

However, if the type of the `List` is unknown statically, this will not work.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but maybe you could write a method like this:

```
static void parseList<T>(String input, List<T> list)
```

Please give use more background for a better answer.